# Can anyone explain the difference between passing the activity context to an inner class and just referencing it with MyActivity.this?

Tags: android, android-context

And which way is better?

Let me know if the question needs clarification.

Comment: That's mostly a personal preference.

Comment: @Pompe de velo - Isn't the main difference then that using MyActivity.this is a lot simpler?

Comment: Depends on the actual situation. If your inner class is private it's simpler, but what about if you make it public and create an instance of it in another class? If private = use `MyActivity.this`, otherwise pass a `Context` to the inner class. That's how I do it.

Comment: @Pompe de velo - I didn't even consider the case of having a public inner class, but what you're saying makes sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have chosen to answer my own question, not because any of the answers are bad, but because while they are equally good, none provide a complete answer.

It seems that one of the main factors to take into consideration is reusability:

Using MyActivity.this to refer to the context means that you will have to modify your code if you ever decide to use the class in another project/class/context.

Passing the context in the constructor and referencing it as a private variable, allows you to reuse the class wherever you want without modifications.

Another factor that will influence your choice is whether your inner class is public or it is private. It doesn't make sense to make an inner class public and then reference the context with MyActivity.this. The application would force close the moment you use the class from another activity. I would argue though, that a public class belongs in its own file, but that is up to the individual developer.

Lastly there is the matter of simplicity, as it is simpler to write MyActivity.this than to implement a constructor etc. This seeming simplicity can come back and bite you, as you can see above, if you decide you need to use the class somewhere else.

I will continue to use MyActivity.this out of simplicity for all inline eventhandlers, but for any other situation it seems that passing the context to the constructor is best practice.

Answer (score 3):

For reusing passing the context is easier as you then can simply copy it to another project. Otherwise you have to change all the MyActivity.this to OtherProjectActivity.this.

But most of all it doesn't matter what you use

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a design issue as having a reference either way will have the same result.  Consider the complexity, the access level and other design elements related to the inner class.

Comment: Thank you. If the result is the same, is there ever a reason to pass the context as a parameter to an inner class? and here I'm referring to the complexity it adds, however little.

Comment: If its a static inner class, definitely. This is really a question about design and object model as the reference is equivalent.

Comment: Sorry, but both your answers are rather vague. Exactly how does it affect things if the class is static?

Comment: If you're using a public static inner class you'll have to pass the Activity as a parameter. If you're using a quick one-off anonymous inner class its better to use Activity.this. If its an inner class (non-static) that gets created or used extensively from outside its parent class a constructor parameter is likely better. If its a private inner class that is used in one or several spots Activity.this is easier.  I'm just trying to say its how you use it that is important.